# How to check the JavaScript array objects are overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects containing start and end range.

```
var ranges = [{
    start: 1,
    end: 5
}]
```

I want to push an object like this without overlapping with the previous start and end range

```
{
    start: 6,
    end: 10
}
```

How to check new object overlapping with the existing objects

Edit:

```
  {
        start: 50,
        end: 100
    },
{
        start: 11,
        end: 49
}
```

Comment: Do you mean filter out time overlaps completely or truncate the time range so that it doesn't overlap the current ones?

Comment: I want to check the object start and end should not be present in the array

Comment: So loop over your existing ranges then, and for each of them check if the start of your new item is lower, and the end is higher ... where is the actual _problem_ with that?

Comment: Using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every would make sense here. Or the other way around, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some - then this can be broken off when the _first_ overlap has been found.

Comment: I have mentioned the problem above in the edit section, i don't want to compare like higher or lower when i am trying to add it should not allow.

Comment: consistency needs to be check here. if your question is relating to PUSH only, then a  simple conditional check would be needed but if this question grows into - an array can not have an element overlapping previous index element, then you can override push, pull, slice, edit operation using a user defined service/class/function. which will always insure that the array element wont overlap in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer thanks everyone for your response.

```
let isValid = timeRanges.every(r => (r.begin != selected.begin && r.begin < selected.begin &&  selected.begin > r.end) && (r.end != selected.end && r.end < selected.begin &&  selected.end > r.end));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this **:**

```js
const ranges = [{
  start: 1,
  end: 5
}];

const rangeObj = {
  start: 6,
  end: 10
};

function checkRangeOverlap(obj) {
  let res = ''
  ranges.forEach((obj) => {
    res = (obj.end > rangeObj.start) ? 'Overlaping': 'No Overlap';
  });
  return res;
}

console.log(checkRangeOverlap(rangeObj));
```